# Run a command on remote server using python

Tags: python, server, paramiko

```
cmd ="some command"
echo "The answer is"
echo $cmd
```

When I try to run the above command using paramiko library in python.

The above command is saved in a variable named command.

stdin,stdout,stderr=ssh_conn.exec_command(command)

The process does not run the "echo $cmd" part of the command.
Please help.

Comment: We need [mcve]. The part of the code for *"above command is saved in a variable named command"* is missing.

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is that you're actually sending over bash shell script, not an actual command to execute. But I agree with @MartinPrikryl that we need more code / context to be able to help.

Comment: The command which i mentioned here is working if i directly run it over the server. 
I understand your concern but trust me there is a working command in line cmd="here". I have also tried by adding the command in  ` ` instead of " ".

Answer (score 0):

First install `paramiko`

```
pip3 install paramiko
```

Then try this code with your own commands:

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    client.connect(hostname="192.168.1.100", username="user", password="pass")
except:
    exit()

commands = ["pwd", "id", "uname -a", "df -h"]
for command in commands:
    print(command, ":")
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
    print(stdout.read().decode())
    err = stderr.read().decode()
    if err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: I do not see how does this answer the OP's problem with *"The process does not run the "echo $cmd" part of the command"*. + Please do not ever suggest anyone to use `AutoAddPolicy` without explaining the security consequences.

Comment: This is not going to solve the exact problem of running "echo $cmd", as mentioned by @MartinPrikryl.

Comment: So please consider confirming the answer, thanks. @NakulChawla