# Run bash script on remote server using python

Tags: python, server, paramiko

```
cmd="some command to run on server"
echo "The solution is"
echo $cmd
```

The above script is saved in "command" variable and is to be run on remote server using python and paramiko.

```
stdin,stdout,stderr= ssh_conn.exec_command(command)
```

The output does not represent the working of the command in last line "echo $cmd" the command saved in cmd variable does not work.

Comment: You have asked this question already: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63931752/850848

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the script on your computer ? If you want the string inside your cmd variable to execute inside your echo you must add backquotes around it

```
cmd="some command to run on server"
echo "The solution is"
echo `$cmd`
```

Comment: Won't simple `$cmd` do the same as `echo \`$cmd\``?

Comment: Yes it will actually, I was just pointing out what was wrong in the above script. Both solutions would be working

Comment: You got to provide more information in your original post then. What is your current output ?

Comment: the out put gives me an error stating "no json object could be decoded"

Comment: Well then it surely have something to do with your command if the error is stored in stderr or with your python script if it crashes

Answer (score -1):

cmd = `some commad`
echo $cmd
Use ` ` quotes to execute your command

Comment: What's the same answer as @clanglai's.